# PHP , Fpdf Parse error: When using AddFont()

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have an issue with displaying what ever on a PDF file when I change the font.

```
<?php
session_start();
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/library/fpdf.php";
$pdf = new FPDF('P',"mm",'A4');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);
foreach ($_SESSION['settings'] as $settings) {
    $pdf->Cell(130,5,$settings,1,1);
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I tried changing the font with other files and I just keep getting random errors like:

> Warning: Unexpected character in input:

or

> Parse error [my path to the ttf file]

Even if I don't print anything in the PDF just leave it blank , I still get an error due to the AddFont,

If I remove

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);
```

and replace it with

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AddFont` function requires a particular type of file to be able to use the font, not just the font file itself. If you take the `DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf` file and upload it [here](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/), it will convert it into the required format for you.

There will be 2 files generated, `DejaVuSans-Bold.php` and `DejaVuSans-Bold.z`. Copy both of these into your project, and then change the line of code to the following:

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSans-Bold.php');
```

There's more information on how to add new fonts on the [following tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm). It has details on how to generate the font files manually on your own PC, however there is an online tool (linked above) that will do it for you:

> Finally, for TrueType and OpenType fonts, you can also generate the files [online](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/) instead of doing it manually.

<sup>*Note: you may get some warnings when you convert online, saying certain characters are missing. If you scroll to the bottom, the converted files will still be available to download, you just won't be able to use any of the listed missing characters in your PDF.*</sup>

Comment: It worked , thanks. But the idea behind this was that my texts will work in UTF-8 and they still dont... can you help me with that too?

Comment: @Innervisions no problem :) I'm not sure what you mean saying they don't work in UTF-8, sorry. It may be worth creating a new question with all the details (what you expect to happen, what is actually happening) and me or someone else will be able to help then.

Comment: Eh, nevermind i found the issue I'm suppose to use tfpdf.php (for UTF-8) languages and not fpdf.php

Comment: @Innervisions ah I see, never realised that before - I've never had to deal with various encodings in the PDFs I've generated so far. Learn something new every day!

Comment: @crazyloonybin Little something to make up for the parade I missed ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks! _**insert parade sounds here**_

Comment: @crazyloonybin *hehe!* welcome; *cheers!* Gotta love a parade though, eh? :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- once I catch up to your rep level, I'll hold the biggest parade the world has ever seen! Haha

Comment: @crazyloonybin I don't want to tie up comments too much as it would look like we're chatting, but yeah... go for it ;-)) and you're doing great I find, after going over some of your other answers where I find to be clear and concise. Keep up the good work. Having gone up so high took me by surprise actually. TBH, I don't know where I made all that rep in what I find to be so little time *lol!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I'm mindful of chatting too! But thank you!! I've been lurking in the shadows on here for too long and got lots of useful information, so trying to give something back now. I don't know everything, but I'm working on it! ;)